# Only make the buttons inside v-list clickable, while disabling the v-list-item content

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I'm using a `v-list` component to show available bundles of a product. Basically, I want to be able to press a button in the `v-list` to remove this bundle (the item on the row of the `v-list`).

Clicking on the button works fine, but the entire `v-list-content` is clickable. Even tho it does nothing, I want to disable it so that the user can only click on the button to the right of every `v-list-item`. Is there a way to do that?

I'm aware that I can add the props `disabled` to the `v-list` tag. However, every child tags of the v-list are disabled, so the button becomes unclickable.

```js
<v-list rounded> <!-- disabled -->
  <v-list-item-group
    v-model="selectedItem"
    color="primary"
  >
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(bundle, i) in editForm.suggested_bundles"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-list-item-content append-icon="mdi-delete">
        <v-list-item-title v-text="bundle"></v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-btn @click="removeBundle(editForm.suggested_bundles, bundle)">
          <v-icon small>mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item-icon>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
```

Any solution for this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you don't perhaps need the `v-list-item-group`, so by removing that, only your button is clickable:

```html
<v-list-item v-for="(bundle, i) in editForm.suggested_bundles" :key="i">
  <v-list-item-content append-icon="mdi-delete">
    <v-list-item-title v-text="bundle"></v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
  <v-list-item-icon >
    <v-btn @click="removeBundle(editForm.suggested_bundles[i])">
      <v-icon small>mdi-delete</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-list-item-icon>
</v-list-item>
```

If you need to use `selectedItem` you can always (re)assign the value in `removeBundle` function. Hopefully this solution will suit your needs.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/yLgQRLL) for reference**

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! :)